# Insert Data using OLE DB Destination

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2008

I have inserted 10 rows of data from Table A to another new table called Test_Table_Destination which I also created inside a TEST server. In the OLE DB Source I put the select statement..

```
  SELECT top 10 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource
```

In the OLE DB destination editor, I choose Table or View - Fast Load.

On my FIRST ATTEMPT - After Running the package, it turned green and became successful.
The 10 rows were added to the Newly created Test_Table_Destination

Now my problem starts here:

On my SECOND ATTEMPT - When I try to change the script in the OLE DB Source to..

```
SELECT top 20 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource
```

Of course my goal is to load the top 20 rows without repeating or duplicating the first 10 rows on my first attempt of running the package so I changed the script into this.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Table_Destination
 SELECT top 20 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource
 WHERE ResourceID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Test_Table_Destination)
```

But it does not work..
So I tried to put the script in the SQL command editor inside the OLE DB Destination editor, under sql command text.. I put this script

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Table_Destination
SELECT top 20 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource
 WHERE ResourceID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Test_Table_Destination)
```

And I keep getting errors.
What should I do with this?
How can I insert data to a new or old table without duplicating or repeating the same previously loaded data?

Ideally it should now repeat the first 10 rows on my second attempt of running the package. I want to see the top 20 rows only.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have any primary key column?or any unique column that may creates differences among one and another column value.

Answer (score 0):

Your  OLE DB Source cannot have an INSERT statement, you only supply a query to SELECT the values you want to be passed on to the destination, so change the source query to:

```
SELECT top 20 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource
 WHERE ResourceID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Test_Table_Destination)
```

Click 'Evaluate' to ensure it's selecting the 20 records you want to insert.

There should be no query necessary in your OLE DB Destination.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question! Let me give it a try

Comment: I still get some errors such as:TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Invalid column name 'ID'.".

Comment: If I put this query it does not work -->

SELECT top 20 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource
 WHERE ResourceID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM dbo.Test_Table_Destination)

but if I remove the sub-query, IT WILL WORK.

SELECT top 20 ResourceID, ShortName, SupervisorID from BI_Test_DB.dbo.Resource

Please help me with this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hmm, hard to troubleshoot without looking at the package.